# aws websocket api integration with cloudwatch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, routes, amazon-cloudwatch

we are planning to integrate api gateway websocket api to cloudwatch logs aws service for a PutLogEvents action with a mapping template for a custom route. we are facing with  UnknownOperationException when integrating. we found that we are missing the headers `X-Amz-Target`, `Content-Type` in the request headers.
Tried [Cloudwatch Logs PutLogEvents action fails with com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException when called from API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755935/cloudwatch-logs-putlogevents-action-fails-with-com-amazon-coral-serviceunknowno)

how can we set the values for those headers in mapping template? or any other suggestions to integrate the cloudwatch logs service?